# The import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Tags: java, appium

I'm getting below 2 compilation errors in Eclipse but I'm not understanding what may be the root cause

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver; //ERROR 1
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class AppiumDriver {
    private AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;    //ERROR 2
}
```

Error 1:

The import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Error 2:

The type AppiumDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your own class from

```
public class AppiumDriver
```

to

```
public class CustomAppiumDriver
```

---

The compiler is reporting errors based on the same name class as you are trying to import. The other way to access the classes from appium lib would be somewhat like:

```
public class AppiumDriver {
    private io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't import two classes with the same name or have import of class of the same name as your class in which this import is. Compiler won't know which class you wan't to use in that line. There are two solutions:

1. Rename your class to something like `CustomAppiumDriver`
2. Remove import and every time you want to use external class type te whole name with package name: `io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver`